# PostgreSQL jsonb - omit multiple nested keys

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

The task is to remove multiple nested keys from `jsonb` field.

Is there any way to shorten this expression without writing a custom function?

```sql
SELECT jsonb '{"a": {"b":1, "c": 2, "d": 3}}' #- '{a,b}' #- '{a,d}';
```

> suppose we need to delete more than 2 keys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to shorten the expression. If your goal is to pass to the query a single array of keys to be deleted you can use `jsonb_set()` with `jsonb_each()`:

```
with my_table(json_col) as (
values
    (jsonb '{"a": {"b":1, "c": 2, "d": 3}}')
)

select jsonb_set(json_col, '{a}', jsonb_object_agg(key, value))
from my_table
cross join jsonb_each(json_col->'a')
where key <> all('{b, d}')    -- input
group by json_col             -- use PK here if exists

    jsonb_set    
-----------------
 {"a": {"c": 2}}
(1 row)
```

The solution is obviously more expensive but may be handy when dealing with many keys to be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

NVM, figured it out)

For this particular case, we can re-assign property with removed keys (flat):

```sql
SELECT jsonb_build_object('a', ('{ "b":1, "c": 2, "d": 3 }' - ARRAY['b','d']));
```

More general approach:

```sql
SELECT json_col || jsonb_build_object('<key>',
    ((json_col->'<key>') - ARRAY['key-1', 'key-2', 'key-n']));
```

Not very useful for deep paths, but works ok with 1-level nesting.

Comment: This works in Postgres 10+ (the operator with an array on the right-hand side was introduced in Postgres 10).